# What is the algorithm used for interp3 in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, interpolation

Given a 3D data set defined by f(x,y,z) at uniform and discrete (x,y,z) values, how does Matlab calculate a value of the function f(x,y,z) at a position that is not from the original data set (eg. x+0.1, y+0.1,z+0.1). This 3D data set could be a 3D image with pixel intesity values at specific discrete x,y,z values.

Comment: Select the name of the function, then do Ctrl-D. This will give you the source code for it. Keep in mind that the source code is copyrighted so be careful if you are planning on implementing something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the 'method' parameter provided, by default (with no method provided) it uses a [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) interpolation, you can also select 'nearest' which is simply finding the nearest point and assigning the same value, or you can use 'spline' and 'cubic'.

for monotonic data (uniformly distributed grid) you can use '*linear', this probably uses a [trilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) interpolation.

edit:
to answer the question in the comment here is an example of trilinear interpolation
say f(x,y,z) is defined for x,y,z belong to {0,1} and i want the value for 0 <= i,j,k <= 1

```
f(i,j,k) = ((f(0,0,0)*(1-i)+f(1,0,0)*i)*(1-j)+ 
            (f(0,1,0)*(1-i)+f(1,1,0)*i)*  j  )     *    (1-k)+

           ((f(0,0,1)*(1-i)+f(1,0,1)*i)*(1-j)+ 
            (f(0,1,1)*(1-i)+f(1,1,1)*i)*  j  )     *      k
```

notice there are 7 linear interpolations here.

Comment: what do you mean by linear interpolation in a 3D data set? If you have a cube and each vertex is say defined as (x,y,z) coordinate of the original data set how would I find the value say at the centre of the cube.

Comment: there's a good explanation of trilinear interpolation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation)

Comment: but generally, given a cube you first do a 1D liniar interpolation on 4 pairs of vertices, now you got 4 new data points on a single 2D plain containing the target point, now you interpolate to pairs of those new points to get 2 more data points on a line containing the target point, and from here it's just one more 1D interpolation.